# Unexpected failure when running python scripts via bash inside a venv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, bash, csv

I have this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/reallymemorable/Documents/environments/trading/bin/python3 1-ccxt_2.py -e bittrex -s BTC/USDT
sleep 1
/home/reallymemorable/Documents/environments/trading/bin/python3 1-ccxt_2.py -e bittrex -s ETH/USDT
sleep 1
/home/reallymemorable/Documents/environments/trading/bin/python3 1-ccxt_2.py -e bittrex -s XRP/USDT
sleep 1
/home/reallymemorable/Documents/environments/trading/bin/python3 1-ccxt_2.py -e bittrex -s LTC/USDT
sleep 1
/home/reallymemorable/Documents/environments/trading/bin/python3 1-ccxt_2.py -e bittrex -s BCH/USDT

sleep 3
/home/reallymemorable/Documents/environments/trading/bin/python3 2-dateConvert.py
sleep 3
/home/reallymemorable/Documents/environments/trading/bin/python3 3-concatCrypto.py
sleep 3
/home/reallymemorable/Documents/environments/trading/bin/python3 4-cutDates_1year.py "$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d "1 year ago")" "$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')" < DailyCryptoPricesFull.csv
sleep 3
/home/reallymemorable/Documents/environments/trading/bin/python3 4-cutDates_3months.py "$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d "3 months ago")" "$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')" < DailyCryptoPricesFull.csv

sleep 1
mkdir $(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
sleep 1
mv -- *.csv "$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')"
```

It pulls 5 different crypto time-series, converts the date format in the dateConvert.py script, joins all 5 cryptos in the concatCrypto.py script, then produces 2 versions of the output for 1 year back and 3 months back.  Then it creates a directory with the current date as the name and moves all the files into it.

This was all working perfectly, but then I realized that I needed to be doing this all inside a venv.  I created the venv and changed my python calls (as you can see above) to use the venv.

But now what happens is the first set of commands execute correctly (the 5 data pulls), but the rest of the python scripts are not executed at all.  (The `mkdir` and `mv` commands do execute correctly.)

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "3-concatCrypto.py", line 33, in <module>
    df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['Timestamp'], how='outer'), data_frames).fillna('NULL')
TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value
getCrypto.sh: 33: getCrypto.sh: cannot open DailyCryptoPricesFull.csv: No such file
getCrypto.sh: 37: getCrypto.sh: cannot open DailyCryptoPricesFull.csv: No such file
```

This indicates that it has started to fail on the concatCrypto.py file, but I know that it actually fails (really, skips) the script before that because the dates are not converted.

I'm guessing it has something to do with how you reference paths inside venvs, but I am not sure.

Here is the contents of dateConvert.py:

```
import csv
import datetime
import time
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = "/home/reallymemorable/Documents/scripts/Crypto/*1d.csv"
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    print(fname)
    # Step 1: Convert the dates
    df = pd.read_csv(fname)
    df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], unit='ms')
    # print(df.head())
    # nameWithDate = str(str(datetime.date.today()) + fname)
    df.to_csv(fname + '-dateFormatted.csv', index=False)
```

And concatCrypto.py:

```
import csv
import datetime
import time
import pandas as pd
import glob
from functools import reduce
import os
from datetime import date


data_frames = []

for fname in glob.glob("/home/reallymemorable/Documents/scripts/Crypto/*dateFormatted.csv"):
   data_frames.append(pd.read_table(fname, sep=','))

df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['Timestamp'], how='outer'), data_frames).fillna('NULL')
print(df_merged)
df_sorted = df_merged.sort_values(by='Timestamp')
print(df_sorted)
# df_oneYear = df_sorted[df_sorted['Timestamp'] == '2019-06-11']
# print(df_oneYear)
df_sorted.to_csv('DailyCryptoPricesFull.csv', index=False)
```

EDIT:

The error seems to be that `glob` is not running in dateConvert.py.

I tried to install it manually, but getting this error:

```
reallymemorable@gort:~/Documents/environments$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
reallymemorable@gort:~/Documents/environments$ python --version
Python 2.7.17
reallymemorable@gort:~/Documents/environments$ source mai_trading/bin/activate
(mai_trading) reallymemorable@gort:~/Documents/environments$ python --version
Python 2.7.17
(mai_trading) reallymemorable@gort:~/Documents/environments$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
(mai_trading) reallymemorable@gort:~/Documents/environments$ pip3 install glob
Collecting glob
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/reallymemorable/Documents/environments/trading/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/reallymemorable/Documents/environments/trading/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/home/reallymemorable/Documents/environments/trading/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/home/reallymemorable/Documents/environments/trading/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/home/reallymemorable/Documents/environments/trading/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/home/reallymemorable/Documents/environments/trading/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/home/reallymemorable/Documents/environments/trading/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/home/reallymemorable/Documents/environments/trading/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/home/reallymemorable/Documents/environments/trading/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/home/reallymemorable/Documents/environments/trading/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/home/reallymemorable/Documents/environments/trading/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 795, in get_page
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/home/reallymemorable/Documents/environments/trading/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/models.py", line 935, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/glob/
```

Comment: and >> 2-dateConvert.py is executed ?? Debug here: pd.merge(left,right,on=['Timestamp'] I think something is null or empty..

Comment: dateConvert is *not* executed.

Comment: ok check >> Debug:  Step 1 in dateConvert.py:  df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], unit='ms').. I suspect in file is a conversion problem (when you read) with that field.

Comment: The error is definitely that glob is not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: *facepalm* I had changed the name of a directory and hardcoded the paths in the `glob` calls.